# How do Chinese people correct their characters?

Tags: handwriting

While practicing writing of simple sentences, I realized that after missing I stroke, I was tempted to fix it the same way I'd do it in English - by thickening the strokes I'd like to keep. I know that Chinese people have a "shorthand" way of making notes. Given the multitude of characters, how do they correct mistakes in writing? Is there a standard way of, say, crossing out a character?

Answer (score 3):

for example this picture，hope to help you:
[image]

Comment: Why down vote? I don't see anything wrong in this answer. It provides an example that what a typical draft would be edited before it is rewritten or retyped. It is actually applicable to any language. Characters that are to be replaced would be simply crossed out. Most people would do the same in English

Comment: Didn't downvote, but while it's one of the perspectives, it doesn't seem to answer my question entirely - it's not hardwriting, especially not the shorthand version. Also there's lots of empty space between lines. Not sure if that's what most Chinese writing looks like, but I imagine it doesn't.